# Gnome's Network manager doesn't instantly detect internet connection losing

Tags: ubuntu, networking, gnome

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with gnome and nowadays I am facing some internet connection problems (cause of my ISP).

I am noticing that, the Gnome Network manager applet doesn't instantly react to the connection status, as opposite to M$ Windows' network manager (or whatever its name) that do instantly react to connection changes!

Is it a know bug? And how can I get it solved?

Thanks.

Comment: What reaction do you expect appart from an info popup?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a bug?  Good question.  Do you want your OS to generate a bunch of network activity polling the internet only to find that 99.9999% of the time it's still there?

Or do you prefer messages constantly popping up telling you that "Your connection is UP/DOWN..." even when you're not using the internet and theres nothing you can (apparently) do about it anyway.

If you prefer the latter I guess you could write your own polling applet - you don't need Gnome's.

Comment: Is that how windows network manager behaves (i.e. annoy users with messages of network status)?